# Select2 parameter for templateResult and templateSelection different (django)

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-select2

I've got a strange problem. I have a product select element item in my web application. Because there are quite many products in the database I've decided to load them dynamically with select2. The issue is that I want to pass an additional parameter (Unit) that would be displayed opposite the select box. So to find a product i use Django as backend and my method looks like this.

```
class FindProductAjaxView(AjaxableResponseMixin, CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm

    def get_ajax(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = request.GET.get('q', None)
        if query:
            products = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=query).values(
                "pk", "name", "unit")
            results = list(products)
            return JsonResponse(data={'items': results}, safe=False)
        else:
            return JsonResponse(data={'success': False,
                                      'errors': 'No mathing items found'})
```

So it returns the pk, name and unit fields correctly. Here is the script I use to create my select2 product inputs.

```
<script>
    function initProductSelect2 (select) {
        select.select2({
            placeholder: "Wyszukaj...",
            ajax: {
                url: '/recipes/find_product',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                language: 'pl',
                data: function (params) {
                  return {
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                  };
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    data = data.items.map(function (item) {
                        return {
                            id: item.pk,
                            text: item.name,
                            name: item.name,
                            unit: item.unit
                        };
                    });
                    return { results: data };
                },
                cache: true
          },
          escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
          minimumInputLength: 1,
          templateResult: formatItem,
          templateSelection: formatItemSelection
        });
        select.siblings('span').find('.select2-selection').addClass('form-control');
    }

    function formatItem (item) {
        console.log(item)
        if (item.loading) return item.name || item.text;
        var markup = '<div class="clearfix" data-unit=' + item.unit + '>' + item.name + '</div>';
        return markup;
    }

    function formatItemSelection (item) {
        console.log(item);
        return item.name || item.text;
    }
</script>
```

The issue lies within the `formatItem` and `formatItemSelection` methods. The item that is passed to `formatItem` is OK. It has all the fields I need (pk, name, unit). But the item that comes into `formatItemSelection` has only id and text fields.

I've been struggling with this issue for several hours but I have no idea. I tried (as you see in the code) to pass the unit parameter as a jQuery data element but I have no clue how to retrieve it. The finest solution would be if the item passed to `formatItemSelection` would have all the fields passed from the controller (pk, name, unit).

Thanks in advance !

EDIT: I use select2 in the newest version 4.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have an answer. In the context of initProductSelect2() i create an `options` object that is populated in `ProcessResults` and then i retrieve my option from there when select event is fired. I also changed the processResults method. Here's my updated code with an alert which displays the unit of the selected product. I init my select2 like earlier but with a second parameter like this `initProductSelect2(select, [])`:

```
function initProductSelect2 (select, options) {
        select.select2({
            placeholder: "Wyszukaj...",
            ajax: {
                url: '/recipes/find_product',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                language: 'pl',
                data: function (params) {
                  return {
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                  };
                },
                processResults: function (data, params) {
                    params.page = params.page || 1;
                    data.items.forEach(function (entry, index) {
                        entry.id = entry.pk;
                    });
                    options = data.items;
                    return {
                        results: data.items,
                        pagination: {
                            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                    }
                  };
                },
                cache: true
          },
          escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
          minimumInputLength: 1,
          templateResult: formatItem,
          templateSelection: formatItemSelection
        });
        select.on("select2:select", function(e) {
            var id = $(this).val();
            var result = $.grep(options, function(e){ return e.id == id; });
            if (result.length != 0) {
                alert(result[0].unit);
            }
        });
        select.siblings('span').find('.select2-selection').addClass('form-control');
    }
```

Comment: I had to do this same thing when triggering a selection and it's frustrating me to no end. There is no reason that params should not exist in the on select event.